# How to write a custom mavenArtifactRepositoryContainer?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin

In my Android project I am maintaining the URL to a local Maven server in a few places in `build.gradle` files:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://example.com/nexus/content/groups/com.example.android.public/" }
    }
}
```

I also maintain dependencies in a Kotlin class within the `buildSrc` folder:

```groovy
object Plugins {
    private object Versions {
        const val android = "3.4.2"
    }
    const val android = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${Versions.android}"
}
```

Is there a way I can define a `mavenCompany` variable in the `buildSrc` Kotlin file and invoke it from the `build.gradle` file(s) in my modules? Basically, I want the same as `mavenLocal()`. One of the related files is [`org.gradle.api.artifacts.ArtifactRepositoryContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ArtifactRepositoryContainer.html) which defines a few constants:

```java
public interface ArtifactRepositoryContainer extends 
                                    NamedDomainObjectList<ArtifactRepository>, 
                                    Configurable<ArtifactRepositoryContainer> {
    String DEFAULT_MAVEN_CENTRAL_REPO_NAME = "MavenRepo";
    String DEFAULT_MAVEN_LOCAL_REPO_NAME = "MavenLocal";
    String MAVEN_CENTRAL_URL = "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/";
    String GOOGLE_URL = "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/";
```

I could not figure out how to write my own.